# "Can't convert between vector values of different size"

Tags: python, c, pyopencl

I'm trying to run a Runge-Kutta 4 on C language. The code is as follows:

```
__kernel void updade_state( __global float8 *q,__global float8 *qm, __global float8 *v){

const int gid = get_global_id(0);
float8 qs;


//k1
f( q, v);
qs = q[gid] + dt * v[gid]/6.0;
qm[gid] = q[gid] + 0.5 * dt * v[gid];

//k2
f(qm, v);
qs +=  dt * v[gid]/3.0;
qm[gid] = q[gid] + 0.5 * dt * v[gid];

//k3
f( qm, v);
qs +=  dt * v[gid]/3.0;
qm[gid] = q[gid] + dt * v[gid];

//k4
f( qm, v);
qs +=  dt * v[gid]/6.0;

//update particle
q[gid] = qs;
```

}

I'm using pyopencl module to access my graphics card ("**gid**") in order to run a simulation of multiple particles much more efficiently.

Apart from the function **f** that is being called in the kernel, the rest of the kernel is being built in a python program, through which it is added the constant value of **dt**, present in my Runge-Kutta code.

However, when I run the whole thing, the following error message shows:

```
<kernel>:52:22: error: can't convert between vector values of different size ('double' and 'float8')
    qs = q[gid] + dt * v[gid]/6.0;
                  ~~ ^ ~~~~~~
<kernel>:53:33: error: can't convert between vector values of different size ('double' and 'float8')
    qm[gid] = q[gid] + 0.5 * dt * v[gid];
                       ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~
<kernel>:57:15: error: can't convert between vector values of different size ('double' and 'float8')
    qs +=  dt * v[gid]/3.0;
           ~~ ^ ~~~~~~
<kernel>:58:33: error: can't convert between vector values of different size ('double' and 'float8')
    qm[gid] = q[gid] + 0.5 * dt * v[gid];
                       ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~
<kernel>:62:15: error: can't convert between vector values of different size ('double' and 'float8')
    qs +=  dt * v[gid]/3.0;
           ~~ ^ ~~~~~~
<kernel>:63:27: error: can't convert between vector values of different size ('double' and 'float8')
    qm[gid] = q[gid] + dt * v[gid];
                       ~~ ^ ~~~~~~
<kernel>:67:15: error: can't convert between vector values of different size ('double' and 'float8')
    qs +=  dt * v[gid]/6.0;
```

Cheers

Comment: Is a double the same as a float8?  Have you tried casting?

Comment: I don't think it is. The value dt is already being casted in the python part. I will edit it above.

Comment: SOLVED: Well, I solved the problem the hard way which I will edit above. Thank you Jiminion for the suggestion!

Comment: Do not edit your question to make it an answer! Instead, write an answer to your own question (that is well accepted). You can even accept, but will not get any reputation.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I will post my solution below then ^^' Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I went around the problem and solved it by casting the value dt and other constants in the kernel, as suggested by Jiminion. This is not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
__kernel void updade_state( __global float8 *q,__global float8 *qm, __global float8 *v){

const int gid = get_global_id(0);
float8 qs;
float  dt, c1, c2, c3;

c1 = 6.0;
c2 = 3.0;
c3 = 0.5;    

dt = 0.0001;


//k1
f( q, v);
qs = q[gid] + dt * v[gid]/c1;
qm[gid] = q[gid] + c3 * dt * v[gid];

//k2
f(qm, v);
qs +=  dt * v[gid]/c2;
qm[gid] = q[gid] + c3 * dt * v[gid];

//k3
f( qm, v);
qs +=  dt * v[gid]/c2;
qm[gid] = q[gid] + dt * v[gid];

//k4
f( qm, v);
qs +=  dt * v[gid]/c1;

//update photon
q[gid] = qs;
```

}

Comment: Glad you got something working.  You could pass dt as a parameter in updade_state().  You could alter it or recast it before use, if needed.